# Add a method to JS prototype not working on the instance from node module

Tags: javascript, prototype, node-modules

When I wrap my code in a local node module, link and import the local module, the behavior of JS prototype changes.

## Putting code together will work

I wrote a code to instantiate an `Observable` and add a method to its prototype. The instance has the method.

```
// main.js
// Add a new method to Rx.Observable.prototype
function someMethod() {...};
Rx.Observable.prototype.someMethod = someMethod;

// Create an instance of Rx.Observable using a function
function getAnObservable() {
  return Rx.Observable.create(...);
}
var observable = getAnObservable();
console.log('>>> observable:' observable);
console.log('>>> someMethod:' observable.someMethod);
```

output:

```
>>> observable: Observable {...}
>>> someMethod: function someMethod() {...
```

---

## Separating code in different files will still work

When I move the instantiation code into a separated .js file, the code still work

```
// a.js
function getAnObservable() {
  return Rx.Observable.create(...);
}
module.exports = getAnObservable;
```

```
// main.js
// import 
import getAnObservable from './a.js'

// Add a new method to Rx.Observable.prototype
function someMethod() {...};
Rx.Observable.prototype.someMethod = someMethod;

var observable = getAnObservable();
console.log('>>> observable:' observable);
console.log('>>> someMethod:' observable.someMethod);
```

```
>>> observable: Observable {...}
>>> someMethod: function someMethod() {...
```

---

## Wrapping code in a local node module will NOT work

Now I move the file `a.js` to a local node module, link the module and import the file. I still get the instance but it doesn't have the method `someMethod` (becoming `undefined`).

```
// someNodeModule/index.js
function getAnObservable() {
  return Rx.Observable.create(...);
}
module.exports = getAnObservable;
```

```
// main.js
// same as previous code
// import 
import getAnObservable from 'someNodeModule'

// Add a new method to Rx.Observable.prototype
function someMethod() {...};
Rx.Observable.prototype.someMethod = someMethod;

var observable = getAnObservable();
console.log('>>> observable:' observable);
console.log('>>> someMethod:' observable.someMethod);
```

```
>>> observable: Observable {...}
>>> someMethod: undefined
```

---

## Question

I don't know why it can't find the extended method on the prototype when I put the code in a local module.

---

## New Edit:

The local node module has its own Rx.

module/package.json

```
{
  ...
  "dependencies": {
    "rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.12"
    ...
  }
}
```

mainProject/package.json

```
{
  ...
  "dependencies": {
    "rxjs": "^5.0.0-beta.12"
    ...
  }
}
```

I use `npm list rxjs` to show the Rx modules. They both use `rxjs@5.0.0-beta.12` but in different location. Is that the problem? How to fix it?

Comment: You mean `module.exports = getAnObservable;`?

Comment: @sabithpocker YES, it's typo.

Comment: I guess, the "main" module and the submodule don't use the same "instance" of the Rx module/class. Try comparing them.

Comment: @Thomas How to compare?

Comment: How do you import `Rx` respectively in the two modules?

Comment: export Rx from the submodule `module.exports.Rx = Rx;` and compare it to the one in the main module `console.log('>>> same Rx', getAnObservable.Rx === Rx)`

Comment: @Thomas It shows `false`.

Comment: So, if the Rx in the submodule, that creates the instances, ain't the same as the Rx in the main module, where you extend the prototype ... well, does this answer this question?

Comment: @Bergi I added the info in the post. Seems they use the same version but different library location. I don't know how to fix it.

Comment: @Thomas Yes, thanks for your help, but I don't know how to fix it.

Comment: Inject Rx into your submodule. Change the concept of the submodule to sth like `module.exports = function takesARxAndReturnsAFunctionCreatingObservables(Rx){ return function(){ return Rx.Observable.create(...); }}`

Comment: @Thomas I'm JS newbie. I never though I'll do this hack way. LOL. Does not `npm` have solution for this dependency?

Comment: "*but in different location. Is that the problem?*" - Yes. It's two Rx instance with different prototypes. "*How to fix it?*" - you could use a global module, but I'm not sure whether that's the best solution.

Comment: @Bergi I see. I'm not sure how a global module works. 

(1) If I use global module, do I need to remove both local Rx libraries in main project and module?
(2) If I need to remove local Rx libraries, do my team members need to install global Rx library manually which can't be done by shared `package.json` and `npm install`?
(3) When I pack my app.js for production, will it automatically use global Rx libraries to pack?

Comment: @李岡諭 1) yes 2)3) those are probably the disadvantages. You might use dependency injection like Thomas suggested, or even better: don't extend prototypes you don't own. Why do you think you need `somemethod` in the first place?

Comment: @Bergi I'm developing a tool for gulp using RxJS which allow you to hook node streams by `Rx.Observable`. I need to add methods like `pipe()` or `hook()` to all instances of `Rx.Observable`.

Comment: @Bergi Another question about bundling js code: If my submodule use different location of Rx library against main project, will my packed `bundle.js` include duplicated Rx libraries?

Comment: @李岡諭, then I'd say the best way would be to not extend the prototype at all but to write the "methods" as functions that consume an Observable. I know, it's not as handy/fluent to write as calling a method on the observable, but it's more robust/reliable and you could rely on duck-typing. If it looks like an Rx.Observable treat it as one, no matter where it came from. That would be my best guess/approach depending on what I know from your project.